How to remove an unpaired value(s) from a data frame column?
I'm just starting to learn R, and I'm trying to figure out how to get rid of values that are unpaired in R.
For example, if this is my data frame:
ID      Value
1        4
1        2
2        3
3        4
3        5
4        5
4        2

I would like to remove row 3 (ID = 2) from the DF.
This is what I tried:
for (i in 1:length(df$id) {
  if (df$id[i] == df$id[i+1]) {
    i <- i + 2
  } else {
    df <- df[-df$id[i]]
    i <- i + 1
  }
}

But I am getting  this error, and it's clear I don't really know how to iterate through without going out of bounds.
Error in if (r15data$pair[i] == r15data$pair[i + 1]) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Is there a better way to try to remove unpaired values? If not, how can I fix my for loop?

We don't need a package for this simple task.
> subset(df, ID %in% which(table(ID) == 2))
  ID Value
1  1     4
2  1     2
4  3     4
5  3     5
6  4     5
7  4     2


One approach, with dplyr, could be to apply a filter, keeping only IDs with more than 1 row.
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), Value = c(4L, 
                                                                   2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                 -7L))

library(dplyr)

df |>
  filter(n() > 1, .by = ID)
#>   ID Value
#> 1  1     4
#> 2  1     2
#> 3  3     4
#> 4  3     5
#> 5  4     5
#> 6  4     2

Created on 2024-06-04 with reprex v2.1.0
